# Installing Ubuntu failed, now i have just a command line

Tags: gnome, command-line, usb

Last night I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB (for which I had to use Bootice on Windows XP to install PLoP Boot Manager on the MDR, since I was unable to boot from USB and have no CD Rom). It was all going fine, BUT the part when all the programs are installed failed. When it all finished and the computer rebooted, I was left with only a command line login and no desktop environment.

Is it possible to install the ubuntu-desktop environment from USB? How? Or maybe I could try to reinstall everything, but how do I boot from USB now that Windows has been erased from the hard drive and I can't use Bootice again?

Thank you.

Comment: will it let you use $sudo apt-get update

Comment: Yes, but it requires me to insert the Ubuntu CD.

Comment: can you cd to /etc/apt and see if you have a sources.list file.

Comment: and I guess you will need an internet connection (I am assuming you do). Will make this easy if you do.

Comment: I did cd and ls and it does list sources.list~ and sources.list.apt-setup. Yes, it has an usb wireless connection and it is already configured.

Comment: posting as an answer so I can format the code properly

Comment: Thaaank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new file called sources.list

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then copy and paste the following in it. (this is assuming you are in the US. It doesn't *really* matter if you are not, it will just be slower since you are further away from the respective mirrors)

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Now try to issue the update command.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If it is able to update the sources try to install the updates.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the updates are all in and you have rebooted and you still do not have a desktop, try issuing

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

it should run through everything and then you will need to reboot to see the desktop.

Hope that fixes it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say you needed to save and close the sources.list file after pasting in the content. I figured you knew that, but just in case. Hit the Esc key to exit from edit mode and then hit Shift + : to get to the prompt and then type wq to save and exit the editor.

Comment: Hmm... OK, already did the file, but it's not working. I think the wi-fi connection got lost, not sure why, it was working a little while ago. I guess I'll try again later, maybe I'll have to reconfigure wi-fi first.